# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 _OBJC_CLASS_$_DDLog" referenced from

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just run command `pod update`.

podfile:

```
source 'https://gitcafe.com/akuandev/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'BlurImageProcessor', '~> 1.0.0'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
pod 'MagicalRecord'
pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 4.0.4-alpha-1'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'MWFeedParser', '~> 1.0.1'
```

The errors shown when building the project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDLog", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MagicalRecord+ErrorHandling.o
      objc-class-ref in NSManagedObject+MagicalDataImport.o
      objc-class-ref in NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.o
      objc-class-ref in NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalObserving.o
      objc-class-ref in NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalRecord.o
      objc-class-ref in NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalSaves.o
      objc-class-ref in NSObject+MagicalDataImport.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: your project is in objective C or swift?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the setup again with CocoaPods and started a demo app with iOS 7.1 64 bit simulator and everything works perfectly fine.

Could you please compare your build settings with the screenshots I attached.

[image]